# Four Equations in Four Unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

> **Four Equations in Four Unknowns**
>   
>   Completely solve the following equation!
>
> $$\begin{eqnarray}
> x&+&y&+&z&+&w&=&10 \\
> x^2&+&y^2&+&z^2&+&w^2&=&30 \\
> x^3&+&y^3&+&z^3&+&w^3&=&100\\
> &&&&&&xyzw&=&24
> \end{eqnarray}$$

This is problem 3 on page 3  of

Mathematical Quickies

270 Stimulating Problems with Solutions

by Charles W. Trigg

Dover Publications, Inc., New York

ISBN 0-486-24949-2

Here is the solution from page 78 of the book:

> By inspection $(1,2,3,4)$ is a solution if the first and fourth equation and satisfies the second and third equations. Since the equations are symmetrical in $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$ the other $23$ permutations of $1,2,3,4$ are solutions also.
>   *But these are all the solutions, since the product of the degrees of the equations is 4!*

I assume that the exclamation mark at the end of the last sentence is a factorial symbol because the product of the degree of the equation is 24. 
This seems to be a property that is similar to the fact that a univariate polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ zeroes. But I can't see how to generalize this to multivariate equations.

Why does this system of equations where the product of the degree of the equations is 24 has at most 24 solutions?

Comment: I am interested to hear what others have to say about this question.  I wouldn't have expected such a convenient result to be true myself.  For clarification, are we restricting the domain of the solutions?  $x^2+y^2=1$ has infinitely many solutions (*the unit circle*)...

Comment: @JMoravitz: thank you, I corrected the typo. I cited the full problem text. I think the domain is $\mathbb{C}^4$

Comment: @JMoravitz: you have two variables but one equation. If you have two equations then you may have only finitely many solutions. circle and line: product of degree is 2, number of solutions is two. Circle and ellipsis: product of degee is 4, number of solutions can be 4. So I think something like $n$ equations in $n$ variables, product of degree is $k$, then there are at most $k$ solutions.

Comment: This is a consequence of Bezout's Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem

Comment: this is a nice problem.............+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** Yes, you are correct that a univariate polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ zeros (counting multiplicity). However, your system are just the roots of a univariate in disguise.

The clue is the *elementary symmetric polynomials* $x+y+z+w$ and $xyzw$. If these unknowns are indeed the roots of the quartic,
$$F(u)=u^4+au^3+bu^2+cu+d=0$$ then,

> $$\begin{aligned}
> x+y+z+w &=10 = -a\\
> x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 &=30 = a^2-2b\\
> x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3 &=100=-a^3 + 3 a b - 3 c\\
> xyzw &=24=d
> \end{aligned}\tag1$$

It is easy to solve for $a,b,c,d\,$ above and we get,
$$F(u)=u^4 - 10u^3 + 35u^2 - 50u + 24 = 0$$
$$F(u)=(u - 1)(u - 2)(u - 3)(u - 4)=0$$
hence these, including their permutations, are all the solutions.

**II.** Let $n_r$ be the number of roots and $n_d$ be the product of the degrees.  By *[Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem)*, then $n_r$ is ***at most*** equal to $n_d$. The observation that your example has $n_r=n_d=24$ is just a peculiarity of the system. If we tweak it slightly,

> $$\begin{aligned}
> x+y+z+w &=10 = -a\\
> x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 &=30 = a^2-2b\\
> \color{blue}{x^5+y^5+z^5+w^5} &=100=-a^5 + 5 a^3 b - 5 a b^2 - 5 a^2 c + 5 b c + 5 a d\\
> xyzw &=24=d
> \end{aligned}\tag2$$

Solving for $a,b,c,d,\,$ they turn out to be rational so,
$$F(u)=u^4 - 10u^3 + 35u^2 - \color{blue}{\tfrac{602}{13}}u + 24 = 0$$
though $F(u)$ is no longer rationally factorable. Like the previous, by including the permutations of the $u_i$, there are again $n_r=24$ roots, but the product of the degrees is different now as $n_d=1\times2\times5\times4 = 40$ so $n_r\neq n_d$.

Comment: Hi @Tito, Thank you for the answer. I think your  first answer is  what  the the author of the recreational math problem has in his mind.

Comment: @miracle173: You're welcome. Incidentally, If you recall, it is also the case that $\sum_{n=1}^k n^3 = \big(\sum_{n=1}^k n\big)^2$ which explains his value $(1+2+3+4)^2 = 10^2 = 100$.